# React build displays javascript on the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

When uploading the code generated from `yarn build` to github, other web hosts, or locally hosting it, I am successfully able to load the index.html page. As far as I can tell, everything works correctly (the index page redirects to the selection page as it should), except for the selection page is displaying a large block of javascript:

[image: classclock screenshot]

The generated HTML markup for this page seems to be normal in that when I inspect the code that is being displayed, it appears between `<script>` tags as it should, except for some reason the code is being displayed on the screen

Comment: I saw your below ' self-answer ' . The problem is not the css code. The problem is that `<script>` tags shouldn't be inside the `<body>` tag, but in the `<head>` of the document. and then `body > *` wouldn't select the `<script>` elements

Comment: @MihaiT Yeah, this definitely would solve the issue mentioned in the question, however in my specific case that would mean the javascript would be loaded before the `<body>` of the page and thus would not be able to `document.getElementById()` since no elements would exist yet. As a react application, the entire app is contained inside a `<div id="root">` element so putting the code up top would mean that the app would not display at all.

In simple cases like analytics I definitely agree that it should be put in `<head>` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparrently you can hide and show the content of `<script>` tags...

So the following CSS in my app was causing this:

```
body > * {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: center
}
```

Solution: Either change the CSS selector to `div#root > *` (i.e. select all children of the actual app rather than children of the `<body>)` or move the `<script>` tags out of the body (thanks to Mihai T for mentioning this in the comments)

*facepalm*